# Best permissions for an upload folder through iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, upload, permissions

I need to allow users to upload pictures from an iOS app and be able to view them later. What is the safest permission set that will allow this to work?

Comment: Where is this folder?

Comment: What do you want to set the permission for? Please clarify .